# Contact Fom 7 - how to add custom HTML inside span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap AND IMMEDIATELY AFTER input.wpcf7-form-control?

Tags: php, filters, hooks, actions, plugin-contact-form-7

Contact Fom 7 - how to add custom HTML inside span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap AND IMMEDIATELY AFTER input.wpcf7-form-control ?
Using the 'Query Monitor' plugin I found that the HOOK which I need to modify is inside the:

'/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/text.php' file, namely **'wpcf7_add_form_tag_text'** hook

My attepmt is:

```
function test($html) {

$html = sprintf(
'<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s<span class="focus-input100-1"></span><span class="focus-input100-2"></span></span>',
sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error );
return $html;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_add_form_tag_text', 'test');
```

...but it does not work

Comment: `wpcf7_add_form_tag_text` is an action and not a filter hook, so you cannot use it like this.